# Post form data and file in one useFetch call in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I want to post form data (uncluding strings, numbers, arrays) AND a file to backend using one `useFetch()` call, in TypeScript.

**What I tried**

If I add strings and a file to the `FormData` instance, all works great.

But if I try to add numbers, or arrays to the `FormData` instance, I get errors from TypeScript (because `FormData.append()` accepts only strings or `Blob`s). I tried to JSONify numbers and arrays and post them as strings, but then I get errors on backend (I don't want to convert anything on backend).

I tried to post form data as simple JS Object - it works, too, but not for a file.

I ended up with the following code, where I decided to post strings/numbers/arrays as JS Object to create new DB record on backend (`createNewBook`), then update it using `PATCH` method and pass file in `FormData` instance (`updateBookCover`).

```js
function useApi(
  query: Object | undefined = undefined,
  method: string = "GET",
  token: string | null = null,
  formData: FormData | Object | undefined = undefined,
) {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();

  const get: typeof useFetch = (url) => {
    return useFetch(url, {
      params: query,
      baseURL: config.public.apiBase + "/api/v1",
      key: url.toString(),
      method: method as any,
      headers: token ? [["Authorization", "Token " + token]] : undefined,
      body: formData,
    });
  };

  return { get };
}

export async function createNewBook(book: Book) {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();
  let authorIds: number[] = [];

  // Convert array of `Authors` to array of ids for backend.
  book.authors.forEach((a) => authorIds.push(a.id));

  const formData = {
    title: book.title,
    authors: authorIds,
    publisher: book.publisher?.id,
    year: book.year,
    pages: book.pages,
    description: book.description,
    contents: book.contents,
  };

  const { get } = useApi(undefined, "POST", authStore.token, formData);
  return await get<Book>("/books/create/");
}

export async function updateBookCover(bookId: number, coverImage: File) {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("cover_image", coverImage);

  const { get } = useApi(undefined, "PATCH", authStore.token, formData);
  return await get<Book>(`/books/${bookId}/`);
}
```

Full module code - https://github.com/hazadus/drf-nuxt-library/blob/main/frontend/useApi.ts

**What I want to achieve**

The code above works well, but it would be great to post everything (form data and files) using one `useFetch` call.

Answer (score 2):

You must need to pass `FormData()` as below

```js
let formData = new FormData();

//append your file or image
formData.append("file", yourfileorimage);

//append another data
const formdata = {
    title: book.title,
    authors: authorIds,
    publisher: book.publisher?.id,
    year: book.year,
    pages: book.pages,
    description: book.description,
    contents: book.contents
};

for (const item in formdata) {
  formData.append(item, formdata[item]);
}

return await useFetch("YOUR-API-URL", {
    method: "PUT",
    body: formData,
    headers: {"cache-control": "no-cache"},
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how you would pass array of numbers, like I do in my `createNewBook()` function, in `formData`?.. You can't just `.append()` it like a string...

Comment: @Hazadus Please share the exact data which you want to pass or you can stringify the data

Comment: I shared it in the example above: 
`const formData = {
    title: book.title,
    authors: authorIds,
    publisher: book.publisher?.id,
    year: book.year,
    pages: book.pages,
    description: book.description,
    contents: book.contents,
  };` + a file. `authorIds` is an array of numbers, `year` and `pages` are numbers. And I don't want to convert anything on the backend (Django REST Framework).

Comment: I just edited my answer. You can use it for loop and append each item on it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I think it won't work, because `.append()` only accepts strings or `Blob`s as parameter. Already tried code like yours. Anyway, thanks, I will try your solution, maybe I missed something.

Comment: Why await a return call which will again need to be awaited on the caller side? Over here `return await useFetch......`

Answer (score 1):

I made a test but simpler to your but the idea is there. This will send a POST using one `useFetch` only.

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input
                type="file"
                @change="fileChange"
            />
        </div>
        <button @click.prevent="sendDataAndUploadFile">Send Data and Upload file</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>

interface IBookData {
    [key: string]: string | Blob
}

const uploadedFile = ref<File | null>(null)

function fileChange(file: Event): void {
    const fileData = file.target as HTMLInputElement
    if (fileData.files) {
        uploadedFile.value = fileData.files[0]
    }
}
const BookData: IBookData = {
    title: 'The Adam',
    author: 'John Doe',
    publisher: 'John Doe',
}

async function sendDataAndUploadFile() {
    const formData = new FormData()
    if (uploadedFile.value) {
        formData.append('cover_image', uploadedFile.value)
        for (const item in BookData) {
            formData.append(item, BookData[item]);
        }
    }
    await useFetch('/api/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
}

</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input
                type="file"
                @change="fileChange"
            />
        </div>
        <button @click.prevent="sendDataAndUploadFile">Send Data and Upload file</button>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

**Edit:** This will be the output

[image]

**Edit**
Example of arrays inside the `BookData`

```js
interface IBookData {
    [key: string]: string | number[] | Blob
}

const BookData: IBookData = {
  title: 'The Adam',
  author: 'John Doe',
  publisher: 'John Doe',
  ratings: [4, 5, 4.5]
}

async function sendDataAndUploadFile() {
    const formData = new FormData()
    if (uploadedFile.value) {
        formData.append('cover_image', uploadedFile.value)
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(BookData)) {
            if (key === 'ratings') {
                formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(value))
            } else {
                formData.append(key, value as string)
            }
        }
    }
    await useFetch('/api/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
}
```

**Edit 2**

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(BookData)) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    for (const rating of value) {
      formData.append(`${key}[]`, rating.toString())
    }
  } else {
    formData.append(key, value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My question is, what if `BookData` in your example would include not only strings, but arrays of numbers, or numbers? How should I include arrays and numbers in `FormData`?..

Comment: I updated my answer. I added a `ratings` inside the `BookData` and updated the interface as well. I also updated the `sendDataAndUploadFile` datas.

Comment: I already tried  `JSON.stringify()`, but my backend swears that there's string data, where integer expected. When I pass object with arrays inside to `useFetch`, all works flawlessly! So, I  thought there's a way to pass data to useFetch without `stringify`ing it...

Comment: Is that a typescript error?

Comment: If you don't want to use stringify, you can try this
`for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(BookData)) {
            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                for (const rating of value) {
                    formData.append(`${key}[]`, rating.toString())
                }
            } else {
                formData.append(key, value)
            }
        }`

Comment: Apologies for the bad format in the coding. I updated my answer you should be able to see the formatted answer at the bottom part.

Comment: Thanks for your examples and your patience! I'll try to refactor my code using your examples and test it with my backend ASAP!

Comment: I tried to use `JSON.stringify()` on array with IDs, as you suggested, and then I get from my DRF backend: `authors: [ "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str." ]`. Exact code I tried: https://github.com/hazadus/drf-nuxt-library/blob/430a546f85188a02c55a057fdf3069cde6908a67/frontend/useApi.ts#L81